# Inverse laplace transform of $\ln$

Tags: laplace-transform

Can someone help me with the following inverse Laplace transform, have not had trouble with any others thus far but this one is catching me

> $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{ \ln(s^3 + s) \} = ?$

Comment: I don't see this in any of my extensive tables, and Mathematica can't find the inverse transform, so I suspect there is no simple form.

Comment: @MarkFischler Interestingly, the inverse LT, as defined by integration on the Bromwich contour, does exist (as shown in my posted solution).  However, it produces an answer,$-\frac{1+2\cos(t)}{t}$ , that is not integrable.  Therefore, $\log(s^3+s)$ is NOT the Laplace Transform of any function as your comment asserts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $F(s) =\log(s^3+s)$  Then, certainly we can write

$$\begin{align}
F(s)&=\log(s^3+s)\\\\
&=3\log(s)+\log\left(1+\frac1{s^2}\right)\\\\
&=3H(s)+G(s)
\end{align}$$

where $H(s)=\log(s)$ and $G(s)=\log\left(1+\frac1{s^2}\right)$.

> **NOTE:**
>
> **The inverse Laplace Transform, $\displaystyle \mathscr{L}^{-1}\{H\}(t)$, of $H(s)=\log(s)$ does not exist and therefore neither does the inverse Laplace Transform of $F(s)$.**

To see this, we note that $\lim_{s\to \infty}\log(s)=\infty$ whereas

$$\lim_{s\to \infty}\int_0^\infty h(t)e^{-st}\,dt=0$$.

We can evaluate, however, the integral given by

$$I(t)=\int_{\sigma -i\infty}^{\sigma +i\infty}\log(s)e^{st}\,dt$$

Choosing the non-positive real axis as the branch cut, we see that

$$\begin{align}
I(t)&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{-\infty}e^{tx}(\log(|x|)+i\pi)\,dx+\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{tx}(\log(|x|)-i\pi)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{-\infty}e^{tx}\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac1t
\end{align}$$

But, the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-st}}{t}\,dt$ fails to converge due the singularity at $t=0$.

---

We can evaluate the inverse Laplace Transform, $\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{G\}(t)$, indirectly by noting that

$$G'(s)=\color{blue}{\frac{2s}{s^2+1}}-\color{red}{\frac2s}$$

Therefore, we find that

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{G'\}(t)=\color{blue}{2\cos(t)}-\color{red}{2}$$

Inasmuch as , $-\mathscr{L}\{t\cdot g\}(s)=-\int_0^\infty t\,g(t)\,e^{-st}\,dt=G'(s)$, we find immediately that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{G(s)=2\left(\frac{1-\cos(t)}{t}\right)}$$

---

We can also calculate the inverse Laplace Transform of $G$ directly.  For $t>0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{G\}(t)&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}G(s)e^{st}\,ds\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}\log\left(1+\frac1{s^2}\right)e^{st}\,ds\\\\
&=\text{Res}\left(\log\left(1+\frac1{s^2}\right)e^{st},s=\infty\right)\\\\
&=\text{Res}\left(\frac1{s^2}\log\left(1+s^2\right)e^{(1/s)t},s=0\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

Expanding $\frac1{s^2}\log\left(1+s^2\right)e^{(1/s)t}$ is a Laurent Series around $s=0$ yields

$$\frac1{s^2}\log\left(1+s^2\right)e^{(1/s)t}=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+1}s^{2n}\right)\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{t^m}{m!\,s^m}\right)$$

It is straightforward to show that the coefficient, $a_{-1}$, on the term $s^{-1}$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
a_{-1}&=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}t^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)!}\\\\
&=2\left(\frac{1-\cos(t)}{t}\right)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

> Putting it all together, we see that
>
> $$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{F\}=-\frac{1+2\cos(t)}{t}$$
>
> but $\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1+2\cos(t)}{t}\right)\,e^{-st}\,dt$ does not exist.  Therefore, $\log(s^3+s)$ is not a Laplace Transform.

Comment: So $\ln\frac{s+3}{s+1}$, $\ln\frac{s+3}{s}$, and $\ln\frac{s^2+1}{s^2}$ are all Laplace transforms, while $\ln(s+3)$ and $\ln(s^2+1)$ are not. Is it the case that any Laplace transform (at least, of a continuous function) tends to zero as $s\to\infty$? Is there a simple characterization of what functions are Laplace transforms [of continuous functions]?

Comment: If there exists a number $s_0$ such that for $s\ge s_0$, $|f(t)e^{-st}|$ is integrable, then, the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that $$\lim_{s\to \infty }F(s)=\lim_{s\to \infty}\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}\,dt=\int_0^\infty \lim_{s\to \infty}f(t)e^{-st}\,dt=\int_0^\infty f(t)\cdot 0\,dt=0$$

Comment: How about my second question? Is there a simple characterization of what functions are Laplace transforms?

Comment: [THIS](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/46286/209_2005_Article_BF01160095.pdf?sequence=1) might be helpful.

Comment: I believe that the inverse transform of $3 H(s) + G(s)$ exists, but the inverse transform of $F(s)$ doesn't. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse transform of $\ln s$ can be computed as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2768299), and the the inverse transform of $\ln(1 + 1/s^2)$ exists in the sense of ordinary functions.

But $\ln(s^3)$ is not the same as $3\ln s$ on a line $\operatorname{Re} s = \sigma > 0$, because $s^3$ will cross the branch cut of the logarithm. It'll be easier to see the issue if we consider $\ln(-s)$ first and define the Laplace transform in terms of the Fourier transform as
$$\mathcal L_{t \to s}[f] = \mathcal F_{t \to \omega}[f(t) e^{-\sigma t}], \\
s = \sigma + i \omega.$$
It follows that
$$\mathcal L_{s \to t}^{-1}[F] =
e^{\sigma t} \mathcal F_{\omega \to t}^{-1}[F].$$
For $\ln s$, we have
$$\mathcal F_{\omega \to t}^{-1}[\ln (\sigma + i \omega)] =
-t_+^{-1} e^{-\sigma t} - \gamma \delta(t),$$
and, since $\ln s$ and $\ln(-s)$ differ by a piecewise constant on the vertical line,
$$\mathcal F_{\omega \to t}^{-1}[\ln (-\sigma - i \omega)] =
\mathcal F_{\omega \to t}^{-1}[
 \ln (\sigma + i \omega) - i \pi \operatorname{sgn} w ] = \\
-t_+^{-1} e^{-\sigma t} - \gamma \delta(t) + t^{-1},$$
which, when multiplied by $e^{\sigma t}$, will not be independent of $\sigma$; also, the support of $t^{-1}$ is not contained in $[0, \infty)$. For these reasons, we cannot construct a functional the Laplace transform of which would be $\ln(-s)$, or $\ln(s^3)$, or $\ln(s^3 + s)$.

An explanation of the dependence on $\sigma$ in terms of the Bromwich integral would be that if $F(s)$ has a branch cut extending to infinity in the right half-plane, then, even if the integral converges, moving the vertical line to the right will change the value of the integral.